# Error setting repeated fields in google protocol buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a message class:

```
message Foo {
     repeated Foo2 field = 1;
}
//Foo2 is another message
```

and in my cpp file:

```
Foo* ci1;
Foo* ci2;
//call some function to to assign values to ci1->field(0)
function( ci1 )
//try to copy ci1-field(0) to ci2->field(0)
ci2->set_field( 0, ci1->field(0) );
```

But I get an error message:
error: 'Foo' has no member named 'set_field'
Why is it reading set_field as a member instead of the function set_ the member field?
I'm new to protocol buffers so any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `*ci2->add_field() = ci1->field(0)`.

More generally you need to understand how the protobuf gets mapped to classes, and how each sort of field is handled. The details are in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#fields).

Comment: I tried to verify the data is there with a "%s", ci2->field(0).str().c_str(), but it crashes, do I need a * in front of ci2? or am I not outputting it right for a repeated field?